# How to stop prevent SamplePlayer and println from calling constantly in a region?

Tags: java, boolean, processing, kinect, audio-player

I'm trying to set up a program with the [beads library](http://www.beadsproject.net/) that plays an audio sample if my Kinect camera detects my hand in a specific region.

However, my boolean setup so far means that it constantly prints in the console that something is being detected and replays an audio sample rapidly until I move my hand away.

I am basically trying to figure out a way to make it toggle the println only once and the sample once. I think it may have to do with `.intersects` that makes it constantly trigger it.

How can I set up the boolean function to fix this?

```
if (blob.getRect().intersects(screenRects.get(0))){
   println("INSIDE_REGION1" + millis());
   String filename = dataPath("bubble.mp3");
   SamplePlayer sp = new SamplePlayer(ac,            
                                      SampleManager.sample(filename));
   ac.out.addInput(sp);           
}
```

I expect it to print INSIDE_REGION1-milliseconds once and then again if I move my hand out and back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a boolean. `false` by default, turns to `true` once your code is fired once, so you can know if the `println()` has been toggled or not. The boolean would turn to `false` again when you remove your hand.

**EDIT :** Something like this :

```
boolean beenPrinted = false;

if (blob.getRect().intersects(screenRects.get(0)) && !beenPrinted){
   println("INSIDE_REGION1"+millis());
   String filename = dataPath("bubble.mp3");
   SamplePlayer sp = new SamplePlayer(ac,            
                                      SampleManager.sample(filename));
   ac.out.addInput(sp);
   beenPrinted = true;
}
```

Comment: How would I tie that into the function? Apologies, I'm very new to this.

Comment: Check the edit to my answer to see an example. You would need to put this into the loop.

Comment: thank you! It even toggles the sample only once. How would you write the loop? I tried to, but it would negate the boolean all together.

Comment: You're welcome ! The loop is the one you should already have if your code is fired multiple times. It should be the one which calls the code you wrote. By the way, if it worked for you, don't forget to accept the answer ;)